# How to Deserialize Jackson container with Generics Generically

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have a signature for a method that looks like this:

```
inline fun <reified TData: IBulkModel?> bulkCreate(path: String) {
    val type = jacksonTypeRef<RequestListWrapper<TData>>()
}
```

There's more to it, but this is the pertinent portion. I have a refied T here in an inline function. My expectation is that the T here would be the actual T for the function for any given call to this, but it's not, it's IBulkModel.

Is there a way to make this work with Kotlin, or am I stuck passing in the complete class?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You're using `TData` as the name of the generic type, and it extends/implements `IBulkModel`, and is passed to the RequestListWrapper as a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

Nested type parameters are lost, even in reified parameters. The only type preserved is the top-level one.

Jackson has a solution for this; you can use the type factory from Java:

```
data class Generic<T>(val t: T)

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()

    val type: JavaType = mapper.typeFactory
                               .constructParametricType(Generic::class.java, Int::class.java)

    val instance: Generic<Int> = mapper.readValue("""{"t":32}""", type)
}
```